# Pine Script help on getting previous candle OHLC

Tags: pine-script

My code is attempting to figure out the following on a 15min chart.

1. Second 15min Candle should be an inside bar
2. Third 15min Candle should break the High of the First 15min candle.

The above condition is for long.
To test the strategy i coded the following.

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="15minbreak")

CdlHigh=0.0
CdlLow=0.0

if(hour(time)==09 and minute(time) == 45)
    CdlHigh := high
    CdlLow := low
    
isInside = ((CdlHigh[1] < CdlHigh[0]) and (CdlLow[1] > CdlLow[0])) // 2nd cdl is inside bar
nextCdlBreak = CdlHigh > CdlHigh[0] // 3rd cdl has given a breakout.

goLong = (isInside and nextCdlBreak)
closeLong = (low < CdlLow[0])

strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,100,when = goLong)
strategy.close("Long",when = closeLong)
```

But when i run the code, i dont see anything.
I"m not sure what i'm missing here. requesting help.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the high of the 9:45 candle to CdlHigh, then using the history-referencing operator `[]` on that variable which is producing the last value, which was 0. Try opening the data window and looking at the variables:

```
plotchar(CdlHigh,'cdlhigh','')
plotchar(CdlHigh[1],'cdlhigh','')
```

For debugging, we could first turn the time into a variable and plot it to see if it's working:

```
second_candle = hour(time)==09 and minute(time) == 45
plotshape(second_candle, style=shape.circle, color=color.black, size=size.small)
```

Now that you've verified that it's selecting the candle correctly you can continue to debug by adding to the condition. An inside bar means the preceding bar has higher high and lower low, from the definition I looked up. You could combine the condition into one variable or use separate variables like so:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="15minbreak", overlay=true)


second_candle = hour(time)==09 and minute(time) == 45
inside_bar = high[1] > high and low[1] < low
special_candle = inside_bar and second_candle

plotshape(special_candle, style=shape.circle, color=color.black, size=size.small)
```

Note I added `overlay=true` to more easily see the plotshape.

There are a lot of different ways you could build the conditions. Here is one. Note, a `[1]` means the last bar, a `[2]` means two bars ago, `[0]` isn't necessary. So for example I define the breakout candle, and then combine it with the variables representing the inside candle and 9:45 candle, used with a `[1]` to indicate that the condition is true for the prior candle.

```
second_candle = hour(time)==09 and minute(time) == 45
inside_bar = high[1] > high and low[1] < low
candle_break = high > high[1]
special_candle = inside_bar[1] and second_candle[1] and candle_break

plotshape(special_candle, style=shape.circle, color=color.black, size=size.small)
```

That should suffice for generating an entry condition. It isn't easy to tell what you intended for the exit condition because you used a history reference for a variable that was used to store the second candle's high. If that was intended, you would need to initialize a variable with the `var` keyword and store the value when second_candle evaluates to true, or perhaps use the `valuewhen` function.

```
var float exit_low = na
if second_candle
    exit_low := low
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will try it out and update . As for exit condition. I'm basically saying that whenever the low of the third 15min candle is breached close the trade. It can happen anytime during the day

Answer (score -1):

i think its strategy cum with screener. thats why not working